# If my 401k money is in Vanguard Rollover 401k then who decides the borrowing terms?

Tags: united-states, 401k

I have changed multiple jobs and every time I change job, I rollover my money into a my vanguard rollover 401k. Now, I am planning to buy a house in a yea or two and I was reading the borrowing from 401k can be a not so good idea IF

1. If you quit or get fired, you have 60 days to pay back the loan. If you cannot pay back the loan it becomes an early withdrawal subject to taxes and the the 10% penalty.

since the money in my 401k is not tied to my current(or any) employer at this point. does "Getting fired scenario apply to me?

Also, what if I have Vanguard + some money with my current employer's 401k and I happen to change the job then what happens?

Comment: I'll bite - How do you have a 401(k) *not* tied to an employer?

Comment: What is a Vanguard Rollover 401k? 401(k) plans are sponsored by employers, so who is the sponsor of your Vanguard 401(k)? Or is this a Solo 401(k) plan from your self-employment and one of its features is that it accepts rollover money from other 401(k) plans? If so, you are the employer and you (while wearing your employer hat) are entitled to fire yourself (wearing your employee hat) or you (wearing your employee hat) are entitled to tell your employer that you are quitting this lousy job and that your employer can go commit an anatomically impossible act. Is this likely to happen?.

Comment: Are you sure that your money is not in a Vanguard Rollover *IRA*?

Answer (score 1):

If you roll your funds from a 401k to an individual Vanguard account it will be in an IRA. Some people talk about IRA loans, but what is happening is that you are given a check for the value of the IRA and you have 60 days to deposit that full amount in another qualified account before being assessed a distribution penalty. The IRS also has rules to prohibit you from making several back-to-back rollovers to try to float the money for longer than 60 days.

Comment: You are assuming facts not in evidence. My question, and Dilip's expansion of it need answering first.

Comment: You're right, I'm making an assumption about where the OP is mistaken; I'm prepared to edit/delete my answer if more information is added to this question.